# Why List element only gets selected when clicked twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-final-form, final-form

I am building a React application and using react-final-form library. I am rendering a select component, but on selecting an item it doesn't get selected. On selecting again, then only it gets selected. I'm not sure why select component state is not getting changed ? Could anyone please check and assist.

Here is the code sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-sunset-9ogwc8?file=/src/Components/Actors.jsx

Regards.

Comment: please attach the sandbox url

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Attached.

Answer (score 0):

In your `NativeSelectField.jsx`, change the `onChange` handler as below:

```
      <NativeSelect
          ...
          ...
          onChange={(event) => {
            input.onChange(event.target.value);
          }}
          ...
          ...
      />
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit unruffled-sara-hs1o3o]

Comment: @Dev9999, check this out!!

Comment: Thanks @Amila. But this NativeSelectField Component is used across many places in the project, removing it might cause regressions. Also extra onChange 'prop' is provided to make this component more customisable and allows the user of the component to write / call a custom change method.

Comment: One thing which is confusing for me is if I comment out this line :

 loadedInitialValues = { ...loadedInitialValues, actorsLsit };

from FormComponent.jsx file then it works perfectly.

To me it seems, I am doing something wrong with my state handling, but what it is and where I am wrong, I am not able to figure out

Comment: One possible issue could be when I am changing the loadedInitialValues, final form Form component's initialValues gets changed and because of that its causing the re-render of the Form component and resetting its values.